# Python Regex Inconsistency

Tags: python, regex

For several different regular expressions I have found optional and conditional sections of the regex to behave differently for the first match and the subsequent matches. This is using python, but I found it to hold generically.

Here are two similar examples that illustrate the issue:

## First Example:

### expression:

`(?:\w. )?([^,.]*).*(\d{4}\w?)`

### text:

J. wang Wang, X. Liu, and A. A. Chien. Empirical Study of Tolerating \nDenial-of-Service Attacks with a Proxy Network. In Proceedings of the USENIX Security Symposium, 2002.

R. wang Wang, X. Liu, and A. A. Chien. Empirical Study of Tolerating \nDenial-of-Service Attacks with a Proxy Network. In Proceedings of the USENIX Security Symposium, 2002.

### matches:

Match 1

1. wang Wang
2. 2002

Match 2

1. R
2. 2002

## Second example:

### expression:

`((?:\w\. )?[^,.]*).*(\d{4}\w?)`

### text:

J. wang Wang, X. Liu, and A. A. Chien. Empirical Study of Tolerating \nDenial-of-Service Attacks with a Proxy Network. In Proceedings of the USENIX Security Symposium, 2002.

R. wang Wang, X. Liu, and A. A. Chien. Empirical Study of Tolerating \nDenial-of-Service Attacks with a Proxy Network. In Proceedings of the USENIX Security Symposium, 2002.

### matches:

Match 1

1. J. wang Wang
2. 2002

Match 2

1. R
2. 2002

### What am I missing?

I would expect this to behave a bit differently, I would think the matches would be consistent. What I think it should be (and don't yet understand why it isn't):

#### Example 1

Match 1

1. wang Wang
2. 2002

Match 2

1. wang Wang
2. 2002

#### Example 2

Match 1

1. J. wang Wang
2. 2002

Match 2

1. R. wang Wang
2. 2002

Comment: Tools such as https://www.debuggex.com/ can be very useful when it comes to working out why your regex is behaving how it is. I would suggest trying it in that.

Comment: @shadow thanks - I've been similarily using pythex and regexr.

Comment: Recently I discovered this page to evaluate the regular expression before use on my code: [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Can you post the exact code that you used for matching and reporting the matching groups? There might be something there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example  you expect the second line to match 'wang Wang'. <<[example 1](https://regex101.com/r/1Ruo6X/2)>> shows clearly that's not what's happening.

After the first match, - which ends with '2002.' - the regex tries to match the remaining part which starts with `\n\nR. wang Wang`. In your first regex the first non-capturing group doesn't match with that, so your group 1 takes over and matches that, ending up with '\n\nR'

```
(?:                   # non-capturing group 
  \w.                 # word char, followed by 1 char, followed by space
)?                    # read 0 or 1 times      
(                     # start group 1
[^,.]*                # read anything that's not a comma or dot, 0 or more times
)                     # end group 1
.*                    # read anything 
(                     # start group 2
\d{4}                 # until there's 4 digits 
\w?                   # eventually followed by word char
)                     # end group 2
```

The same applies to your second regex: even here your non-capturing group `(?:\w\. )?` doesn't consume the `R.` because there are a dot and some newlines in front of the initials.

You could have solved it like this `([A-Z]\.)\s([^.,]+).*(\d{4})`: See [example 3](https://regex101.com/r/1Ruo6X/4)

Comment: Yeah, those are both true statements, but the focus of my question was to the fact that the matches for each example are not *identical*. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: I see. That changes your question. And my answer. Hold on.

Comment: With regards to your answer, thanks, I hadn't realized that this would occur before matching something further in the text, thanks!